# Why is drag & drop so much smoother when adding "overflow: auto"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am making a CMS for a website. In the CMS I want to make a drag/drop/select -able index.

Dragging and dropping on a placeholder was not really smooth. But after I added `overflow: auto` to the div's where you can drag/drop/select, it is way more smoother and easier to work with.

Can someone explain me why this is happening?

It only shows if you have many div's in your webpage. (Like in an almost finished website.)
This happens in Chrome and Firefox. (I didn't test it in other browsers.)

[With overflow auto](http://fiddle.jshell.net/8rs79/3/) <-- smoother

[Without overflow auto](http://fiddle.jshell.net/8rs79/4/) <-- It doesn't do what you want

Comment: It would be much better if you reduced the test case to the essential code rather than copy-and-pasting the entire HTML/CSS/JS into jsFiddle

Comment: Also, why did you open a new question instead of updating the old one?

Comment: Curious: why are you using that alternative JSFiddle domain? Why not link to the real http://jsfiddle.net/8rs79/3/ instead?

Comment: I can't actually see a difference between the two other than the scroll bars. Performance is the same for me.

Comment: @AlainJacometForte - performance is going to be relative to the browser/version that you view it in, some browsers handle the rendering better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must think about the HTML elements. Every HTML element is wrapped within its own 'box'. For each box, you can set its CSS properties like `height`, `width`, `margin`, `padding`, and so on. Each box is designed to expand with its content, even when you give it a set `height`. This state is known as `overflow: visible;` and is the default for every element.

In your case, you are dragging elements within an element to another element. Let's break this down a little. Before we begin dragging, our element lives within another element, inheriting its properties as well. The child element will do its best to fit within the parent element. When we drag the child element, jQuery is allowing the child element to be free from the parent element, and it will no longer inherit the parent element's properties. The child element's content will now expand to its own CSS properties until you drag it into another parent element, at which point it will inherit the new parent's properties.

In the same sense that the child is affected by the parent, the parent can be affected by the child element as well. After all, its default is `overflow: visible;` and wants to show all the content that is contained within it. So if the parent is `100px` in `width` and the child is `200px`, the child will be visible for `100 px` outside the parent's original size.

As designers want to contain our elements to a fixed size, whether it is a `px` value or `%` fraction based on the parent element, so we need a way to prevent child elements overflowing outside of our parent element. This is were CSS `overflow: hidden;`, `scroll;`, and and `auto;` comes into play. I do want to note that there are `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` properties, however, I won't cover them too much as they are self-explanatory. `Overflow: hidden;` will simply hide the content that would overflow outside the parent element. This option will give no scrollbars for the user to view the overflowed content. So `Overflow: Scroll` shows the scrolling bars so that the user can scroll and see hidden overflowed content within the parent element. This option will always show vertical and horizontal scrollbars. Note: This is why there are `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` properties, however with `overflow: auto;`, they are not necessary.

`Overflow: auto;` is the solution for having only the necessary scrollbars for the content, and as a bonus, if the content does not overflow, no scrollbars are shown. So when we look at your `div.sortobject`, without `overflow: auto;`, it will attempt to visually stretch out to fit it's child elements. When you begin to drag elements around, the potential parent divs are overflowing visually trying to resize both for the child element and the jQuery helper element, the element that shows the user where to drop content. Setting `overflow: auto;` will cause the parent element to always retain its set `width` and `height`, so that when you drag your child element, it will appear smoothly as no potential parent elements are resizing. jQuery loves to calculate current exact dimensions of the elements it affects, and will also improve the animation as well.

I hope this gave some insight.

Comment: in my opinion, I don't think jquery has anything to do with the child element's placement within the parent element. This seems more like the inherited functionality of html and css. All JQuery does is provide the animation and keeps record of positioning. Unless there's proof that JQuery has some role.. I have my doubts.

Comment: in his case jquery does have to do with it. He is moving a child element out of the parent element into another parent element. It's affect the content size of the parent divs.

Comment: yes, he is using jquery to do this functionality, but if I hardcode the final placements using html, I can almost guarantee you that the placements will be shifted.

Comment: what is happening with his code, is that it's dynamic. Yes you can hard code and get a static webpage. That's boring and not what he wants his page to do. If you hard code a div to auto size with its content and place 2 elements in it, a 500px by 500px and a 100px by 100px, when using jquery to drag the 500px element out of the parent div, the parent div will shrink to 100px by 100px.

Comment: no no, I understand what you mean, I'm saying that it's not the jquery that's causing the shrinking, it's the html. Jquery has nothing to do with the resizing unless you tell it explicitly. All he's doing is using the animation properties. Html/css styling does the rest. I wanted to illustrate my point by saying that if you create a static webpage, regardless of jquery, the behavior will not be as expected due to the width of the div.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, its just that because there is jquery involved and the static html wasn't setup correctly at the time, JQuery had major impact.

Comment: jquery doesn't do this.. simple as that. Until you can literally show me proof, then I'll believe you. It's part of the w3c standards for the html to behave like that. Jquery simply does NOT do what you think it does. Look at the link tremor posted below for visual effects. Jquery does not illustrate the behavior you're talking about anywhere in their docs at all.

Comment: his examples shows all his styling is in his css, for his animation he's using jquery ui sortabble, so I'm still failing to understand why you're still connecting the two. Did you see jquery ui sorttable and did you see code where jquery is playing around with the widths of the dom that's being manipulated? The difference between his examples has been purely css.

Answer (score 4):

The default value for overflow is "visible", meaning that the overflow is not clipped. It renders outside the element's box.

The value auto means that if overflow is clipped, a scroll-bar should be added to see the rest of the content.

The smoothness effect that you refer to is simple that in default overflow, rendering outside the element's box will probably be slower/jumpier than when set to auto which moves the rendering into the actual element. This was especially noticeable for me in firefox looking at your fiddle example after moving all the elements to one column then trying to move them back.

Surprisingly in IE11, there was no noticeable difference between auto/default that I could see.

Please Read: [Official W3 Documentation for Visual Effects](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html)

Comment: You're answer seems logic, but i'm not sure if it is the right answer. But thank your for your time +1

Comment: @STP38 - I can assure you this is correct, review the official documents from the w3 here - http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html

Answer (score 3):

In the overflow-auto, I noticed there is a horizontal scroll bar in some of your boxes. If you take off any overflow, the div width will expand due to the content contained within them. When you get fatter divs, you'll get mixed div widths, and can cause quirky div placements when you drag them within a parent container. Think of a bucket with fat apples and small apples, versus a bucket with apples of all the same size; the position of the apples will be scrunched up differently between the two.

Bucket of fat apples with small apples: (**div width of different sizes**)
If you don't believe me that the div's are fat, you made the under lay of the divs the same size, but open up your link without the overflow = auto, you'll notice your images go over the right hand side of the border.

[image: zoomed in view of content without overflow-auto]

Bucket of apples of equal size (**div width of same sizes**)
With overflow set to auto, if you get beyond a certain width, the scroll bar will appear, and the width of the content will flow through, not changing the width of the div; so nothing gets quirky.

[image]